# Try Catch, Function returns x values, but returns clause has x-1 variables

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x, try-catch

**Disclaimer**

I came across an not so well documented issue so I decided to share it and show the solution I found.

This is a very simple problem with a very simple solution, I just didn't found any other topic mentionning it.

I hope this can help someone, someday.
If you have a better approach for this let me know!

---

**Context**

In `ContractA`, I have a function `getInfo()` that returns 3 parameters :

```
function getInfo() public pure returns (uint type, uint id, string memory name) {
  return (0, 1, "info");
}
```

In `ContractB`, I have a function `retreiveInfo()` that uses a try catch block to call `ContractA.getInfo()`.

```
function retreiveInfo() public view {
  try ContractA.getInfo() returns (uint _type, uint _id, string memory _name) {
    // Do something with _type and _id
    // Compiler warning, unused variable
  } catch {}
}
```

---

**Problem**

The problem is that I only need 2 values out of the 3: `_type` and `_id`.
So the compiler is giving me a warning for an unused variable.

I tried to use this syntax:

```
try ContractA.getInfo() returns (uint _type, uint _id, )
```

But compiler returns error "Unexpected trailing coma in parameter list".

So I tried not to include it at all:

```
try ContractA.getInfo() returns (uint _type, uint _id)
```

Again, compiler error "Function returns 3 values, but returns clause has 2 variables".

---

**Solution**

The solution I found is to use an temporary variable:

```
try ContractA.getInfo() returns (uint _type, uint _id, string memory)
```

Comment: It is a quite common trick for C like languages. You could write the last part as an answer so the question can be mark as resolved.

Comment: That's right, I learned about this by doing more research but I still haven't seen this mentioned anywhere for Solidity, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

The solution I found is to use an temporary variable:

```
try ContractA.getInfo() returns (uint _type, uint _id, string memory)
```

Comment: Add explanation for the rationale behind using a temporary variable.